# My script isn't running even if 2 colors are the exact same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I have a script that says if the color of a square in this array is not the same as the color on the screen (a gameObject in my game) the square should disappear. But instead all of the squares disappear even if the color is the exact same as the screen! Can some one help me with this? Thank you! This is the code that's supposed to do this:

```
foreach(SpriteRenderer square in squares)
        {
            if(square.color != colorScreen.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color)
            {
                square.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this thread from the Unity forums is relevant? https://answers.unity.com/questions/787056/comparing-2-color-variables.html

Comment: I tried all of the answers on that post but they didn't really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. For some reason when I copied all of the colors at the same time they came out tinted, making them slightly off from the colors I needed to compare them to. So I just copied and pasted the colors one by one and that seemed to work.